# display value of button in textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap and I want to display my value of button in textbox when I clicked it and my textbox show my value of button but its value doesn't remain and textbox become empty early

```
<input type="submit" value="5000t "class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" id="btn1" onclick="myf()" >
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt" name="txt">
```

```
 function myf() {
     var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
     var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
     txt.value = btn1.value;

 }
```

Comment: Your `submit` triggers a `postback` which reloads the page, after which your `textbox` is empty again.

Comment: its working fine for me see the working example on jsfiddle:-http://jsfiddle.net/BtkCf/170/

Comment: @ZiNNED only if it is inside a form….

Comment: hey are you using form tag or not?

Comment: @TilwinJoy True, but without knowing the rest of the code and seeing the symptoms, it seems like the most logical explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You should not to use a "submit" input type, which actually posts the form (as zinned pointed out), but a simple button, like:

```
<input type="button" value="5000t "class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" id="btn1" onclick="myf()" >
```

Of course you will need another submit button to send the form.

Answer (score 0):

Above code is working fine ..... but while integrating it with your code it make be possible page is getting refreshed or submit button is triggering a  **postback** which makes the textbox empty.

One thing which cab be done is instead of type as **"submit"**  normally use **button**